# an instance of a generator class (recursive)

Tags: python, recursion, generator

Let's say we have this recursive function (generator)

```
data = [1,[21, 22, [231, 232, 233]], [31, 32, 33]]

def listgen(data):
    for each in data:
        if type(each) is int:
            yield str(each)
        elif type(each) is list:
            g = listgen(each)
            for i in g:
                yield i
        else:
            continue
gen = listgen(data)
print ' '.join(gen)
```

the output is:

```
1 21 22 231 232 233 31 32 33
```

Now... how can I write it as a class, because I need to define .close() method for that generator?

Comment: Why do you need to define `.close()`?

Comment: That's not the output I'd expect, why isn't the result strings? Also, you shouldn't use `type(each) is int`, use `isinstance(each, int)` etc... (it's rare to need to check for an exact type)

Comment: this is a simplified case. In the end in a web app I'll be streaming some data (produced recursively) from a database via WebOb.app_iter and the only way to close session (to the database) is by closing it in method .close() in my generator.

Comment: Can't you just place it in a `finally` clause? It should run when all values are used up or once the generator goes out of scope.

Comment: I think you can catch the `close` calls as `GeneratorExit` exceptions in your function-based generator. In Python 3.3, if you use the new `yield from` syntax this work straightforwardly even for recursive generators (otherwise you need to have your own code to propagate the calls).

Comment: Solves my problem nice and easy. Thanks!
Still question can be answered :) Because it seems like not a simple thing to keep the states in generator object.

Comment: +1 for @JonClements - type-checking is unpythonic, and this is a particularly bad way to type-check. The best solution here is to try and iterate through the item, and yield the string representation on exception. If you really **have** to type-check (for example, to distinguish a string from a generic iterator), then use ``isinstance()``.

Comment: Although it's not the essence of the problem, thanks for the advice. I'll remember it for future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `close` on a generator, it raises a `GeneratorExit` at the point where its execution is currently paused. You can catch that exception and do your cleanup in the `except` block before re-raising the exception (you're not allowed to ignore it).

It's a little more complicated for recursive generators, since you need to propagate the exception up the recursive stack manually. But even that isn't too hard. Here's a version of your generator that, when closed, prints "cleaning up" on each level of its execution. If you close it just after it yields 231 from your example data set, you'll get that three times, one for each layer of nesting in the list. In your real use case, you can replace that with code to close your database connection, or do whatever other cleanup work you have to do.

```
def closable_listgen(data):
    try:
        for each in data:
            if type(each) is int:
                yield str(each)
            elif type(each) is list:
                g = closable_listgen(each)
                try:
                    for i in g:
                        yield i
                except GeneratorExit:
                    g.close()
                    raise
            else:
                continue
    except GeneratorExit:
        print("cleaning up")
        raise
```

Python 3.3 makes this a bit simpler, as the new `yield from` syntax automatically propagates calls to `close` up the chain of generators for us:

```
def closable_listgen33(data):
    try:
        for each in data:
            if type(each) is int:
                yield str(each)
            elif type(each) is list:
                g = closable_listgen33(each)
                yield from g
            else:
                continue
    except GeneratorExit:
        print("cleaning up")
        raise
```

For good measure, here's how you could implement the generator as a class (which was what you originally asked for):

```
class list_gen_class(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.iterator = iter(data)
        self.child = None

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        while True:
            if self.child:
                try:
                    return next(self.child)
                except StopIteration:
                    self.child = None

            value = next(self.iterator)
            if isinstance(value, int):
                return str(value)
            elif isinstance(value, list):
                self.child = list_gen_class(value)

    def close(self):
        if self.child:
            self.child.close()

        print("cleaning up")
```